# How to handle security token in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I m doing performance testing of application which has login.I took the token from response body and pass in another request which is submitting the login page.

But interesting thing is that i see two different tokens in the first page one in response header another response body .So question is which one is to grab.

Comment: Try both. There is no rule of sending unique ids in header or body. Totally depends on programmers choice.

Answer (score 0):

Which token to use depends on the application that you are using (and the way it is designed).

So, the best (and first) thing is, find out which security token is passed in the next page, by analyzing the http requests using HTTP trace tools (ex: Fiddler, Firebug etc) manually.